# Facebook iOS sdk search encoding

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, encoding, facebook-ios-sdk

Please help with search string encoding. Simple request like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=max&type=user
```

works pretty good, bud when I try to search in cyrillic:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=макс&type=user
```

I've got null result. What encoding should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is right encodings; First time i forgot replace spaces with pluses.

```
searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
searchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```